# Gradle load properties from file and use it in liquibase task

Tags: gradle, liquibase

I am trying to load properties and use it in liquibase task. I am able to load the properties and able to print it out. But when I use it in liquibase task, gradle complains that properties are not found.

I am using:

```
classpath 'org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:1.1.0'
```

Loading properties:

```
def springApplicationProperties = "src/main/resources/application-${System.env.SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE}.properties"
def springProps = new Properties()
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("${springApplicationProperties}")
springProps.load(is)
println "${springProps['spring.datasource.url']}"
```

Liquibase block:

```
liquibase{
    activities {
        main {
                changeLogFile 'src/main/database/changelog.groovy'
                url ${springProps['spring.datasource.url']}
                username ${springProps['spring.datasource.user']}
                password ${springProps['spring.datasource.password']}
         }
    }
    runList = 'main'
}
```

And I am getting

> No such property: $springProps for class:
>   org.liquibase.gradle.Activity

Looks like springProps is not visible in the liquibase activity. I tried to use ext and project scope, both not visible in liquibase block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work this way:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
      mavenCentral()
   }

   dependencies {
      classpath 'org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:1.1.0'
   }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.liquibase.gradle'

ext.springProps = new Properties()
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/lol.properties")
springProps.load(is)

liquibase {
    activities {
        main {
                url springProps['spring.datasource.url']
                username springProps['spring.datasource.user']
                password springProps['spring.datasource.password']
         }
    }
    runList = 'main'
}
```

You unnecessarily added `${}`. I've changed script a bit while trying out myself - but it has no side effects.

Comment: Thanks @Opal, it is working perfectly. So, when do you use ${}? When do you not?

Comment: You need to use either `"${value}"` (will be evaluated as a GString) or just `value` if *value* is of type `String`. Try with `GString` as well to see if it works.